# Is there a function variable in PHP like in JavaScript?

Tags: php, function, variables

In JavaScript you can have:

```
var blabla = function(arg){
  ...
};
```

Is there something like this in PHP?

I know about `create_function()`, but it's really complicated to stuff your code in a string argument.

Comment: I'm curious as to the use case for this. I've found that anonymous functions in an OO architecture (when done properly) are rarely needed. You *may* be using the wrong solution for your specific problem (maybe I'm digging into the question too much as it has been specifically answered, but I'm still curious :))

Comment: I'm not using OOP in this case, I'm still a beginner in that area :) basically I have a function A and need to create a small function B inside it, which I only need inside A. If I define the function normally than it conflicts with outside functions that have the same name (and I think it can be accessed from outside too, which I dont want). That's why I was wondering if I can have it as a variable...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since PHP 5.3 you can create anonymous functions like this:

```
$var = 1;
$func = function( $arg ) use ($var) {
     return $arg + $var;
};
```

The `use` clause is required to access variables defined outside the anonymous function.

If you want to change an outside variable in the anonymous function you have to declare it as an reference (by adding an `&` in front of the `$`) in the `use` part:

```
$var = 1;
$func = function() use ( &$var ) {
   $var = 42;
}
$func();
// $var == 42 now
```

Otherwise changes made in the anonymous function will not be propagated to the outside.

Comment: thanks! I was wondering if it's possible to use outisde variables because I couldn't do it with create_function :( If you change `$var` does it change outside too?

Comment: Yes, it does; `use` allows it to change outside variables. Just wondering, though, does declaring `global $var;` within the anonymous function work?

Comment: By default one can’t change outside variables, but you can use a reference to allow this. I updated my answer.

Comment: @Sven - Explicit "pass by reference" is deprecated as off 5.3 (http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php). I would imagine that applies to this situation as well?

Comment: @Demian: The example provided by Sven is not a "call-time pass-by-reference" example. The usage of the reference-operator is perfectly legal in this situation. "call-time pass-by-reference" is when you add the reference operator to the argument passed into a function, such as `$b = func(&$a);` - this is deprecated.

Comment: @Stefan: Cool, wasn't sure if it was applicable to this situation or not. +1

Answer (score 5):

They are called anonymous functions. In [PHP >= 5.3](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) you can do:

```
$func = function($a, $b) {
    return $a + $b;
};

$result = $func(3, 4); // returns 7
```

You can even have closures:

```
$c = 5;
$func = function($a, $b) use ($c) {
    return ($a + $b) * $c;
};

$result = $func(3, 4); // returns 35
```

But be aware: the following JavaScript snippet can only be reproduced in PHP using references:

```
var c = 5;
var f = function(a, b) {
    return (a + b) * c;
};
var r = f(3, 4); // returns 35
c = 6;
r = f(3, 4); // returns 42
```

In PHP this must look like:

```
$c = 5;
$func = function($a, $b) use (&$c) {
    return ($a + $b) * $c;
};

$result = $func(3, 4); // returns 35
$c = 6;   
$result = $func(3, 4); // returns 42
```

Prior to 5.3 you have to use `create_function()` to create anonymous functions.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is available in php 5.3.X

http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php

```
<?php
$greet = function($name)
{
    printf("Hello %s\r\n", $name);
};

$greet('World');
$greet('PHP');
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Anonymous functions are available since PHP 5.3.0. [link](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php)

Answer (score 1):

The syntax is very similar to that of JavaScript; for your particular example, it would be something like the following:

```php
$blabla = function($arg){
  ...
};
```

The only difference is replacing "var" with "$", and adding a "$" before "arg".